Is a 4-1/2" header adequate over a window in a bearing wall?
I’m installing Andersen 400 double hung windows. I have 87” between subfloor and top plate. The windows are 46.125W by 68.875H. There is 4.5 of frame and sash below glazing. If I use a header 4.5H I just barely squeeze in at 18”. Is this stupid? Should I see if I can alter the order?
This is a load bearing wall, 13’6” with roof pitch of 5/12

4.5" header is deficient for a ~4' window; You should be using a double 2x6 header minimum; larger is needed if two story house or heavy snow loads, so you lose at least another inch.

Seeing there are floor to ceiling windows, needing to be above 18 inches seems weird.

Floor to ceiling windows are tempered glass which is significantly more expensive.
As for the 2x6, I’m under the impression it is used out of convenience

Are you open to using something sturdier than a normal dimensional member for the header?

I am… adding steel where the 1/2” ply goes? Or?

Or this? Proper window header for 6-foot window & understanding the span tables?

Double 2x6 isn't enough, either over about 36". Double 2x8 or triple 2x6 are more appropriate.

your math doesn't work for me.  18 less 5.5 inches (2x6 dim) is 12.5, what else are you putting in the 12.5"?

There are 4.5” of window below where the glazing begins
